# SubQuery using IN operator

Tags: mysql, sql, select, in-operator, find-in-set

> I have a table named 'user_permission' there is a column named location_ids and **data type is varchar(255)**. I stored here value like **10,27,36**. Now I want to use this 'location_ids' in a **IN comparison operator**. The following query I have tried, but I did not get my expected result.

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `name` SEPARATOR ',' ) as name FROM location WHERE `remove` = 0 AND id IN(up.location_ids)) AS name FROM user_permission AS up
```

> but if I provide IN(10,27,36) instead of IN(up.location_ids) then it's working.

Comment: Easy. See normalization

Comment: What's the value like in up.location_ids field?

Comment: @almasshaikh my value is 10,27,36 in up.location_ids field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

Try this:

```
SELECT up.id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.name) AS `name`
FROM user_permission AS up 
LEFT JOIN location l ON FIND_IN_SET(l.id, up.location_ids) AND l.remove = 0
GROUP BY up.id;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`name` SEPARATOR ',') AS NAME 
        FROM location 
        WHERE `remove` = 0 AND FIND_IN_SET(id,up.location_ids)
      ) AS NAME 
FROM user_permission AS up;
```

Comment: yes, your second solution is working, will you give me some clarification of this query?

Comment: @mizan3008 IN operator required values you can't specify string instead of different values. To achieve this in MySQL you can use FIND_IN_SET() function

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `name` SEPARATOR ',' ) as name FROM location WHERE `remove` = 0 AND id IN(select location_ids from user_permission)) AS name FROM user_permission
```